# JavaScript: Download Static website as a zip file and display the website

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a **static website** that needs to be completely secured (images, JS, Html), the contents of the website are available in a *.zip* file.

After user login and Authorization (JWT), is it possible to download and unzip the file in local storage and serve the static website from local storage?

Comment: No, you can't unzip a file on the clients machine. That would have to be a manual task or done via some software on the local machine.

Comment: I was thinking of the Browser's local storage.

Comment: If you download and unzip your website on a client computer, you may be able to run it locally. But you cannot 'run' a website from the  browser's local storage